# HTML Object over a SWF

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have a SWF Video player on my webpage. I want to draw a div tag over it with a high z-index to act as a popup on it . Its a very generic popup. Hence I cannot make it as a part of swf. but, SWF seems to have  very high zIndex and would not allow any HTMLO entity  to sit over it. How do I achieve this or is there an alternate solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some arguments that have to be passed to the SWF file in order to be able to achieve that. In the HTML representation, inside the object tag you should put:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

and...

```
<embed wmode="transparent" ...
```

A similar value should apply if you're using a JS library to render the SWF object.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a param to the flash object `<param NAME="wmode" VALUE="transparent">` this puts it back in the "flow" and  allows other html elements to go on top

oh and add the wmode="transparent" to th embed tag

Comment: adding the <param NAME="wmode" VALUE="transparent"> to the flash object help for browsers other than FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

A fast & dirty technique is to replace swf with a black / white image (just a different class for the swf container with a repeated background image) every time you show your overlay div and then change it back to normal when the overlay div is close.

Another technique is using iframe for swf but that's not too fancy I guess :)